# Word VBA unhandled error not displaying a message

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Template with VBA.

Wherever I need to I handle my errors with either a "On Error Resume Next / On Error Goto 0" round a call to a collection that might fail, say, or a full error handler (On Error Goto label: / Resume exit_label:)

Tools Options is set to Break on Unhandled Errors

I have found that for this template (only it seems) that unhandled errors are not being reported.  The VBA code just stops running without telling the user anything.

I have tried exporting all VBA modules / forms, saving the template as a .dotx, closing and reopening then saving as a .dotm again and adding the code back but same problem persists.

Other templates for this client work fine.  A deliberately added delete for a non-existent bookmark causes an error to be shown.  The same delete call is ignored by the iffy template BUT the code stops running so it isn't doing Resume Next.

If I add a full error handler to the procedure concerned it does error and reports via my msgbox code.

In some respects this wouldn't matter, anywhere I am expecting errors to be a possibility I handle them but I have a certain amount of code that deals with images in headers and they are prone to errors.  At this point I want the code to error where they happen so I can analyse how to get around the error, just telling the user isn't going to get the template working.  What I have at the moment is the code "dying" and it is very hard to track where without putting in loads of debug statements and seeing where they stopped.

Has anyone seen something like this before?  Could I have set something for this template specifically to tell it to not error on unhandled errors?

Other templates on the same machine error quite happily.

The template is very complex so I don't have the option to make it from scratch.  Turfing out the VBA and putting it back didn't fix it.  If I have to I can add handlers for all procedures but that shouldn't be necessary as errors won't happen once I have tightened up the code.

Any help really appreciated - for a few days I thought it was just VBA dying when working with images, now I really it is something more general than that.

Comment: I've often had problems like this when dealing with ActiveX objects. Are you using any of those?

Comment: Hi. No ActiveX objects.  There is ribbon manipulation but not anything I haven't done before and the other templates that work also have it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found the source of the problem.

I had used a couple of standard procedures we have in various projects for conveying busy/not busy to the user - we call them InterfaceOn and InterfaceOff.  They change the cursor, switch off screen updating, etc.

One line for the Off proc is "Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelDisabled".

I hadn't realised how severe that line is, it appears to stop the errors being reported and the code just dies.  The help for it warns it is risky but doesn't explicitly state that it'll kill VBA on an unhandled error.

The InterfaceOn procedure has the line that reverses the EnableCancelKey restriction.

These procedures are used a lot so I am surprised this issue hasn't shown up before.  Have removed the EnableCancelKey lines for now.  No particular need to be that dramatic with this project.